# place a wet sponge using setblock command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Does someone know how to place a wet sponge?

I tried to get the dataTag but it doesn't have a dataTag so I tried `/setblock ~ ~ ~ wet_sponge` and that also didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wet sponges are sponges with a data value of 1, so use `sponge 1` for a wet sponge:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ sponge 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In Minecraft 1.13 and later versions, the Flattening happpened so wet sponges now have the ID of just `wet_sponge` and the command given in the question will work.